# Copy all elements while sorting by attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XML

```
<root xmlns:temp ="temp.com">
  <testNode name="a">
    <sample/>
  </testNode>
  <testNode name="b">
    <sample/>
  </testNode>
  <testNode name="c">
    <sample/>
  </testNode>
  <testNode name="d">
    <sample/>
  </testNode>
  <testNode name="b">
    <sample/>
  </testNode>
</root>
```

I would like to write a transform that copies over everything while sorting the testNodes by the value of the name attribute.

The expected output is:

```
<root xmlns:temp ="temp.com">
      <testNode name="a">
        <sample/>
      </testNode>
      <testNode name="b">
        <sample/>
      </testNode>
      <testNode name="b">
        <sample/>
      </testNode>
      <testNode name="c">
        <sample/>
      </testNode>
      <testNode name="d">
        <sample/>
      </testNode>
</root>
```

It is possible the namespace is throwing me off, but I cant seem to get the results to sort.

The XSLT I have tried so far is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:temp="temp.com"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="temp:root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="temp:testNode">
        <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the XSLT you have tried? Also, you mention namespaces, but the namespace prefix you declare in your XML isn't actually used anywhere. Is your XML accurate (i.e is it really `<temp:testNode>` and not just `<testNode>` perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: This is just sample code, which is formatted similarly to what I actually need to transform.

Comment: It is important to show a _representative_ input document, i.e. one that actually leads to the problem you are describing. Please edit the question.

Comment: This sample is formatted identically, it perfectly represents my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Given the revised info in your question, there are a couple of issues with your current XSLT and source XML:

1) `<xsl:template name="temp:root">` should be `<xsl:template match="temp:root">`.  i.e. you need to use `match` to target an element to be transformed, rather than `name` which allows you to call a template.

2) Your source XML declares the `temp` prefix, but doesn't use it.  You should use:

```
<root xmlns="temp.com">
  <testNode name="a">
    <sample/>
```

...to create a default namespace (it doesn't matter that the prefix is different to your XSLT's prefix; they're just aliases for the real namespace).  This then means any elements which don't have a namespace assume the `temp.com` namespace.

Or

```
<temp:root xmlns:temp="temp.com">
  <temp:testNode name="a">
    <temp:sample/>
```

Whereby you prefix the elements which are defined in your `temp.com` namespace with the `temp` prefix.

Here's an XSLT Fiddle with both fixed: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBto

NB: If you want your XSLT to be namespace agnostic you can also use the `local-name()` function.

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='root']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name()='testNode']">
      <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Generally that's not a good idea, since there's a performance overhead to calling the function, and you lose the benefit of namespaces; but it can be helpful in various situations; particularly whilst developing if you're unsure whether an issue's related to a namespace related problem.

---

### Original Answer

Use the `xsl:sort` element documented here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_sort.asp

Example: [XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqm)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" /> <!-- keeping utf 8 rather than 16 as this will be big -->
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- By default, copy everything as is -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- but sort the child elements of our root element by their name attribute -->
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
            <xsl:sort select="./@name" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```